# In production bad url shows Internal Server Error instead of customized 404

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have created a simple handler404 according to documentation. In local it works fine, for example when user tries to access an url that does not exist the handler of 404 error is called. But in production it shows a classic "Internal Server Error" and I can't understand why.

The handler are these:

`view.py`:

```
def handler500(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, "maintenance/error500.html", status=500)


def handler404(request, exception):
    context = {}
    return render(request, "maintenance/error404.html", status=404)
```

EDIT:
From log a I have obtain this, what is the meaning?

```
GET /session/987567865850/ HTTP/1.1" 500 141 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0
```

Comment: i think you can just add inside your templates 404.html and 500.html.you do not need a views  or a urls that should handle that.at least for me it works fine when debug=False even in production.

Comment: In fact I can't understan why for me, in production, it does not work... In local it works fine with Debug=False, it loads 404.html or 500.html.. But in production raise Internal ServerError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Moved from an edit to the question by the OP to an answer.*

Create a middleware class that handles the 404 exception:

```py
class Custom404Middleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, Http404):
            return render(request, "maintenance/error404.html", status=404)
```